# Is a beta coefficient of 0.3441 strong?

Tags: regression

I am wondering if there is a table or some reference that explains the strength of the beta coefficient.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meaning of p-values in regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14928/meaning-of-p-values-in-regression)

Comment: That question was about p-values, this one is about beta. I think that makes it different.

Comment: Define what you mean by the "beta coefficient".

Answer (score 1):

It depends of the phenomenon that you are studying. If you can tell me more about your regression, I could try to interpret it.

By the way, you should do a t-test, to check if your beta is statistically different from zero. You could check this link to understand what I'm talking about: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test.

Answer (score 0):

Any book on regression will explain the $\beta$ coefficient.

$\beta$ refers to the standardized coefficient. It is a measure of how much the dependent variable changes when the independent variable changes by 1 standard deviation.  (But see comment below about econometrics).

Is it strong? That is context-dependent. If you tell us the context, someone here may be able to answer.

Comment: In econometrics $\beta$ refers to a coefficient, standardized or not.

Comment: OK, good to know. In social sciences they use $\beta$ for standardized and B for not standardized.