# What F-test is performed by $\texttt{lm()}$ function in R, at the end of the output?

Tags: r, regression, anova, model-selection, f-test

I was wondering what is the F test (in general) that is done by the function $\texttt{lm()}$ in R.

I mean you can  do different F tests, which one does it chose and how? For instance in a linear regression setting, I can fit a certain model with $\texttt{lm()}$ , but (before running the code) how do we know against which model it will be compared to?

For instance look at this: 
[image]

For instance my model here is of the form $$Y_i= \beta_0+\beta_1x_{i1}+\beta_2x_{i2}+\beta_3x_{i1}^2+\beta_4x_{i2}^2+\beta_5x_{i1}x_{i2}+\epsilon_i$$ but, before running this code, what F-test could I have expected to get out of $\texttt{lm()}$? And what test (here) has actually been performed?

Comment: The f-test compares the fit of an intercept only model to the model you've specified and verifies if the additional terms has any significant difference. When your p-value is lesser than the desired significance you would conclude that your model is indeed "better" than just using an intercept.

Comment: See [Interpretation of R's lm() output](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5135/interpretation-of-rs-lm-output) and [How to interpret the output of the summary method for an lm object in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59250/how-to-interpret-the-output-of-the-summary-method-for-an-lm-object-in-r/59251#59251) each of which have an answer that gives some information relating to this question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The $F$ test always tests against the intercept-only model (`y ~ 1`) unless the model has not intercept, then a zero-mean model is used (`y ~ 0`). In your case, this means that the null hypothesis $\beta_1 = \dots = \beta_5 = 0$ is tested.

Comment: Thank you! So If I wanted to test only $\beta_3=\beta_4=\beta_5=0$, what should I do? Should I fit the model (using $\texttt{lm()}$) with less explanatory variables?

Comment: You appear to have a sample size of 11. This is too low for this number of predictors.

Comment: @Euler_Salter Fit both models explicitly and then run `anova()` on it, e.g., `m1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + I(x1^2) + I(x2^2) + I(x1 * x2))` and `m2 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)` and finally `anova(m2, m1)`.