# Calculate p value for Pearson's R

Tags: correlation, p-value

I have a bunch of bivariate correlation tests for which $R$ has already been calculated.

Is it possible to figure out the p-value for each $R$ knowing only (in addition) the number of data points $n$?  If not, then what else do I need to know and how do I calculate it?

(I also have results for bivariate regressions, including F, sigma, coefficient, coefficient sigma, intercept, intercept sigma if they are of use).

Comment: It depends on how the data for each $R$ calculation are related.  If they are not independent, then you need to account for that. More fundamentally, given that you have carried out regression calculations, why are you focusing on $R$? Most likely what you want to learn can be read directly from the regression output, as explained at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5135 and similar threads.

Comment: What do you mean by "if they are not independent"?  $r^2$ is in the region of 0.5-0.8 for all my tests, so the variables are not independent of one another (hence me being interested in p values).  Or do I misread you?

Comment: I mean independence *between calculations*. If, for instance, you are testing the correlations between random variables $X$ and $Y$ and $X$ and $Z$, then those tests are not independent because they share data. It is worthwhile giving some thought to the underlying statistical model of random variation in the values because that is a good indicator of how to proceed with testing.

Comment: Ok, got it.  If I calculate a p value for each test on its own, won't that stand independently?  Obviously as the tests themselves are correlated I can't just multiply the p values together to get a p value for all tests.  But I wasn't planning on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an algorithm from Numerical Recipes:

PFromT(T_Value, DF) = BetaI(DF /2, 1/2, DF / (DF + T_Value^2))

PFromR(R_Value) = PFromT(|R_Value| / SQRT((1 - R_Value^2)/DF) , DF)

The calculation of P from r uses the function that computes P from t, which uses the BetaI function.

You could also compute P from t using this Excel formula:
=TDIST (t, df, 2)

Comment: The t value from your formula (in the first argument to PfromR) matches the t value for the parameter (not intercept) in my bivariate regression, which is confidence inspiring :)

Comment: What is the BetaI function? Is it a function in Microsoft Office Excel ? How would that translate into mathematical notation (to use it outside Excel)?

Comment: @SideshowBob . I don't follow your comment...