# How to understand t-value in R's lm()?

Tags: r, regression, lm

It's similar to the post [Interpretation of R's lm() output](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5135/interpretation-of-rs-lm-output?newreg=537edb7e3e574479ba4efe796cfa22b5).

```
lm(formula = iris$Sepal.Width ~ iris$Petal.Width)
```

however, just a point that I can't understand for the explanation of t-value.

[image]

It shows that, t-value is the ratio from the first two values

```
t-value = estimate_mean/std.error
```

Questions: Is this t-value exactly the t-score in student's t distribution?

Based on my understanding, from the definition, t-score is calculated as follows. 
[image]

If assuming a null hypothesis that response residual mean is 0, the correct t-score in this lm() case, in my understanding, should be as follows.

```
 t-score given H_null = estimated_mean / (std.error/sqrt(n)) 
                      = sqrt(n) * estimated_mean/std.error
```

**Therefore, t-score I derived is sqrt(n) times larger than t-value given by lm() ....** Any one know which part is wrong above? Thanks!

Comment: 1. What is the source of the orange image? 2. You seem to be confusing the standard deviation and the standard error in the ordinary one sample t-test (the orange image shows one, then you say the other; they're different). 3. Testing a regression coefficient is not (usually) the same as performing an ordinary one-sample t-test.

Comment: @Glen_b, the orange image is the one I summarized from http://stattrek.com/probability-distributions/t-distribution.aspx. could you provide some more details on how to test a regression coefficient please?

Comment: @HappyCoding No, because you have a more fundamental problem as I already explained in my previous point (2). The fact that you just ignored it completely concerns me. Given (3), it might be better to look at the one sample t-statistic throughout, get that sorted out and then if you still have a question about regression, to ask about it separately (since dealing with the other issue will change what you ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation in the orange image is for a single sample. If a sample is drawn from a normal distribution 
with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, then $\bar{x}$ is normal 
with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$.

Hence $\frac{\bar{x}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$ will have a standard normal distribution. However, if we estimate $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ from the sample, by the estimated standard error of the mean, $s/\sqrt{n}$, (where $s$ is the standard deviation of the sample), then

$\frac{\bar{x}-\mu}{std.err(\bar{x})}=\frac{\bar{x}-\mu}{s/\sqrt{n}}$ has a $t$ distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

The orange image is consistent with what I just said.

But then you said:

> t-score given H_null = estimated_mean / (std.error/sqrt(n))

This is not correct. Note that the standard error of the mean is $s/\sqrt{n}$, where $s$ is the standard deviation of the data.

The t-statistic in regression is slightly different (though analogous in form; its $t=\frac{b-\beta}{s.e.(b)}$ where $b$ is the estimated coefficient).

It's important to understand the problem here with the more basic case first.

Comment: thanks @Glen_b for pointing out t distribution is different from t-statistic in regression. follow yours suggestion, I did some search and read in http://stattrek.com/regression/slope-test.aspx?Tutorial=AP. it's much clearer now.

Comment: @HappyCoding Thanks for the heads up; I'll edit my answer a tiny bit; that should make things clearer for later readers (because there's fewer sources of confusion, the central issue about the standard error is clearer)

Comment: thanks @Glen_b! That's great! It could be even better if you can also explain a bit on the differences and connections between t-statistic in sampling and regression, besides the formula difference as you pointed out above.

Comment: thanks. for comments are very helpful. I just highlighted here **Note that the standard error of the mean is s/sqrt(n), where s is the standard deviation of the data.**