# Help interpreting regression

Tags: r, regression

these are the results I get using R on my database , can someone help me interpret the results

```
Call:
lm(formula = brevet2016 ~ diversification2013 + specialisation2013 + 
    depensesenRD2013 + KH2013, data = base)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-230.29  -51.53   -8.63   27.68  891.67 

Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         -1.839e+02  6.304e+01  -2.917  0.00448 ** 
diversification2013  7.174e+01  3.925e+01   1.828  0.07094 .  
specialisation2013   3.511e+00  3.341e+00   1.051  0.29612    
depensesenRD2013     3.979e-04  2.626e-05  15.153  < 2e-16 ***
KH2013               4.000e+02  1.188e+02   3.367  0.00112 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 119.1 on 89 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7782,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7682 
F-statistic: 78.05 on 4 and 89 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

More specifically, what does intercept,estimate, 1Q,3Q indicate? – user6465283 42 mins ago

Comment: more specifically, what does intercept,estimate, 1Q,3Q indicate?

Comment: I think that your question has already been answered on [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/5135/28500), between the question itself and the accepted answer. That page doesn't specifically describe the intercept, but that's a standard part of a regression analysis like the other regression coefficients. If that page still leaves you with questions, please edit this question to specify what remains unresolved.

Comment: (1) Be sure to look at @EdM's link. (2) Brief comments on your output to compare with (1): Your model is $Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{1i} + \cdots + \beta_4x_{4i} + e_i.$ P-val for t test of (Intercept) indicates $\beta_0 \ne 0;$ for remaining four t tests we see that $\beta_2$ and maybe $\beta_1$ not sig diff from 0. So maybe consider dropping predictor variables 2 & 1 from your model. In info about residuals: `1Q` and `3Q` label first and third quartiles, respectively.