# Regression analysis Interpretation

Tags: r, regression, interpretation

How do I interpret these results? Specifically, what does this regression analysis show us? How do we determine which values are statistically significant? I don't have problem with the coding. I just don't understand how to interpret the results.

```
Regression analysis of causes of systolic blood pressure!
==================================================================
                               systolic blood pressure            
                    ----------------------------------------------
                                blood pressure (mmHg)             
                    Just cholesterol level       Basic Model      
                             (1)                     (2)          
------------------------------------------------------------------
Age                                               0.512***        
                                                   (0.109)        

Cholesterol Levels         0.042**                  0.023         
                           (0.019)                 (0.019)        

Constant                  121.360***              98.245***       
                           (4.871)                 (6.822)        

------------------------------------------------------------------
Observations                 303                     303          
R2                          0.015                   0.082         
Adjusted R2                 0.012                   0.076         
Residual Std. Error   17.433 (df = 301)       16.857 (df = 300)   
F Statistic         4.637** (df = 1; 301)  13.445*** (df = 2; 300)
==================================================================
Note:                                  *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Comment: This is not the standard R output from a linear regression model. What code produced this? Is this from some special contributed package? Can you clarify what about it you are having trouble with?

Comment: Related: [Interpretation of R's lm() output](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/5135/).